# Basic knowledge about Nodes with Java

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes

I get really confused with Nodes, every Node has an `item` Datatype and a Node datatype called `next`. When we have 3 nodes and we want to delete the middle one for `ex`, `Nodes x`, `y`, `z`. With `x.next=y`, `y.next=z` and `z.next=null`. What does this code do?

```
Node y=x.next;
x.next=y.next;
```

I know that it deletes a Node, but how? In my mind, `Node y=x.next` makes `y.next=y` but then how we delete it? Because `x.next=y.next` should show the `y` Node again.Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Why would `Node y=x.next` make `y.next=y`?

Comment: I know I'm not correct , I want an explanation , that's what I have in my mind , because x.next shows y , so when we type y=x.next , we give y its own value (?) . That's my question really

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `next` property as a kind of pointer (though the actual term in Java is reference).

Let's look at each node as a box, which contains a `next` reference pointing to another box.

The initial situation is:

```
-------           -------            -------
| x   |           | y   |            | z   |
|  next---------> | next------------>| next----> null
------+           ------+            ------+
```

Now, when you write `x.next=y.next`, you get:

```
-------           -------            -------
| x   |           | y   |            | z   |
|  next-----+     | next-------+---->| next----> null
------+     |     ------+      |     ------+
            +------------------+
```

So Node x points to Node z. Node y is **not** deleted, but you can't reach it from x and you can't reach it from z. Therefore you can say it was removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

consider
`X-> Y ->Z`,
Thus X.next points to Y.
Y.next points to Z

Thus, if we set

```
X.next=Y.next,
Y.next=null
```

The list is as below because Y.next is Z. The list now is as below.
`X->Z` and there is no point to node Y.

Thus, Y is no longer part of the list and is also not pointing to any node in the list.